# Nearest neighbor and bayes error rate

Tags: machine-learning

I am not able to solve this to get 1.6 at most error rate. Can someone help me out?

> **$3$-Nearest Neighbor Analysis**
>
> Show that the asymptotic error rate of $3$-NN classifier is at most 1.6 times Bayes optimal classifier.

My try:

[image: answer try]

Comment: You should (a) type out this short question and (b) include in your question what you have tried

Comment: updated the things now

Comment: An improvement, but it would have been better if you had also typed in your attempt using MathJax

Comment: Actually new to this platform and this stream so not soo much familiar with the things will keep things updated using matjax in future